# Choosing the pivot for the duplicate keys algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, duplicates, quicksort

I am trying to understand how to choose the pivot when trying to find the duplicate keys in an array. Most examples that I have seen always chose the first element as the pivot, pretending this element is duplicated in the array. What if it's not the case? How to choose correctly the pivot?

Suppose an array `a[lo...hi]` and v the partitioning element, `v = a[lo]`. We also have 2 more indices gt and lt where

- `a[lo ... lt]` are less than v
- `a[lt ... gt]` are equal to v
- `a[gt ... hi]` are greater than v

So the idea is to scan from left to right until i > gt :

- `(a[i] < v)` : `swap(a[i], a[lt]), i++, lt++`
- `(a[i] > v) : swap(a[i], a[gt]); gt--`
- `(a[i] == v):  i++`

The idea is very similar to quicksort partitioning and I would like to know how to correctly choose the pivot in this case.

Comment: I don't think the 'duplicate keys algorithm' is well-known enough that it can be assumed that everyone knows what it is. You should elaborate.

Comment: ok, I will update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether you choose the pivot duplicate or not. Your algorithm should try to find the duplicate element recursively and it doesn't stop until the duplicate key is found.

```
 /*
 *assume that all element are positive, reutrn -1 when there is no duplicate keys
 */
int duplicate_key(int a[], int lo, int ho) { 
 if (ho - lo <= 1) return -1; //no duplicate keys when there is no more than 2 keys
 a[lo ... lt] are less than v
 a[lt ... gt] are equal to v
 a[gt ... hi] are greater than v
 if (gt - lt > 1) return v;
 return max(duplicate_key(a, lo, it), duplicate_key(gt, hi));
}
```